# Create and Configure connection by executable

Tags: windows, batch-file, remote-access, ras

I have occasional discomfort about having to be setting up a RAS modem connection in over 300 PC users, have sought some method so that each user gets me an .exe or .bat file to run something on your PC this connection is created with the already pre configured data and find nothing

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14614465/3959875)?

Comment: Hello, the explanation of the creation of the connection is in this [ULR] (https://support.earthlink.net/articles/dialup/create-a-dial-up-networking-connection-on-windows-7.php), but it is very tedious for my users all these configuration steps. I want to make an executable file to create all these settings by my rules automatically. Any ideas?