# batch file to connect and disconnect from vpn connection

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

**connect.bat**

```
rasdial myvpn
```

**disconnect.bat**

```
rasdial myvpn /DISCONNECT
```

....I assigned those two files a keyboard shortcut to run them and they work perfectly.

---

**QUESTION**: is it possible to make a single .bat that does the following:

```
if(connected)
   disconnect
else
   connect
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

- Based on `ping` in case the VPN server IP is always the same:

  ```
  ping -n 1 1.2.3.4 && rasdial myvpn /disconnect || rasdial myvpn
  ```

  Replace 1.2.3.4 with your VPN server ip (use `ipconfig /all` when connected) and put this in your batch file or directly in the shortcut properties prepending with `cmd /c` in the latter case.
- Based on connection name:

  ```
  ipconfig|find/i "myvpn" && rasdial myvpn /disconnect || rasdial myvpn
  ```

  Replace `myvpn` with your VPN connection name

Comment: you're a genius, second method works perfectly. Thank you wOx

Comment: I tried this method but an alert is shown and told me that the username and password is not correct. However, I've already filled in the username and password while setting up the VPN in the Network console, so I think I should not include them in the BAT? (typing both information in a BAT seems not secure)

Comment: @KitNg, as per [Establish a VPN connection in cmd](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14614465) use `*` for password: `rasdial myvpn myusername *`

Comment: With the use of *  , it requests me to input the password everytime I connect. Is there any way to use the saved credential in my VPN property? I'm using PPTP. Thanks.

Comment: @KitNg, [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) can do it: `nircmdc rasdial myvpn`

Comment: @wOxxOm my VPN service can only be connected through single-sign on application with has password and security question. Is there a way i can modify above script to use for my need ?