# Creating a Windows VPN Server w/ a Batch File?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vpn

I know it's possible via some GUIS on windows that you can create a vpn server with relative ease. I was wondering if this is possible via the command prompt/ a Batch file.

Comment: This looks like your best bet. [http://serverfault.com/questions/58469/create-a-windows-vpn-connection-from-the-cmd-line](http://serverfault.com/questions/58469/create-a-windows-vpn-connection-from-the-cmd-line)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another post that may help you with that.

[Establish a VPN connection in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614465/establish-a-vpn-connection-in-cmd)

If you want a user interface to easily execute this command, I can create one for you. Hope this was some help to you.

Comment: I like it... However I want to make a VPN _server_ and not a _client_. Thanks.

Comment: To create a VPN server through batch alone is impossible, you need to port forward on your router in order for it to work.

Comment: However, if the port is forwarded, then how would I do this?